# RDS and Django virtual enviornment connection issue on AWS

Tags: mysql, django, amazon-web-services, amazon-elastic-beanstalk, amazon-rds

I am an experienced software engineer but I am new to AWS and cloud services. I have a Django app that relies on MySQL that I wish to host on Elastic Beanstalk (EB). I recently have created a new app/environment on EB and an empty Django project that works fine both on localhost and from my AWS domain.

I just created a MySQL RDS instance and was able to connect to it via MySQL Workbench and the fresh Django application in the virtual environment. I have migrated all the basic tables that are prepackaged just fine and can access them on localhost.

However, when I deploy the Django app from my virtual environment, Django is no longer able to connect to the RDS instance showing the following *"settings.DATABASES is improperly configured. Please supply the ENGINE value. Check settings documentation for more details.
Request Method: GET."*

Error is pictured here:
https://i.stack.imgur.com/ObzFH.jpg

Here is my DB configuration in settings.py:

```
if 'aakspdrcvlie60.ckoc8jkc3t2e.us-west-2.rds.amazonaws.com' in os.environ:
    DATABASES = {
        'default': {
            'ENGINE': 'django.db.backends.mysql',
            'NAME': os.environ['ebdb'],
            'USER': os.environ['USERNAME'],
            'PASSWORD': os.environ['PASSWORD'],
            'HOST': os.environ['aakspdrcvlie60.ckoc8jkc3t2e.us-west-2.rds.amazonaws.com'],
            'PORT': os.environ['3306'],
        }
    }
else:
    DATABASES = {
        'default': {
            'ENGINE': 'django.db.backends.mysql',
            'NAME': 'ebdb',
            'USER': 'USERNAME',
            'PASSWORD': 'PASSWORD',
            'HOST': 'aakspdrcvlie60.ckoc8jkc3t2e.us-west-2.rds.amazonaws.com',
            'PORT': '3306',
        }
    }
```

Am I missing something here? Is EB not supposed to interact with an RDS instance? If not, how can the settings be "properly" configured?

Thank you.

Comment: According to [this document](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/elasticbeanstalk/latest/dg/create-deploy-python-rds.html) it appears that AWS is automatically setting certain environment variables and is expecting to be able to use those to connect. Have you tried using these values in your database config dictionary?

Comment: Yes, I am using those variables. They gave me "aakspdrcvlie60.ckoc8jkc3t2e.us-west-2.rds.amazonaws.com" as hostname and "3306" as port.

Comment: Looking at your settings it seems alright, have you confirmed that Django/EB is actually sourcing the correct settings object? When Django throws that error page you can get a shell and print variables, I'd suggest manually checking your config there and ensure that its actually loading this file.

Comment: A shell? Where can I interact with a shell?

Comment: Did you create you RDS separately out of EB and then you want to connect it to EB? If yes, it is not recommended to do so, and you have  to create it through EB as it do many configuration like security groups and IAM user and other stuff. It is one click step.